# Initializing a 2D numpy array from a string like with numpy matrices: np.matrix("1, 0; 1, 2")

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, matrix, initialization

With `np.matrix`, one can quickly (in the sense of typing) initialize a matrix from a string:

```
np.matrix("1, 1+1j, 0; 0, 1j, 0; 0, 0, 1")
```

```
# output:
matrix([[1.+0.j, 1.+1.j, 0.+0.j],
        [0.+0.j, 0.+1.j, 0.+0.j],
        [0.+0.j, 0.+0.j, 1.+0.j]])
```

Is there a way to do this with `np.array`?

This does not work:

```
np.array("1, 1+1j, 0; 0, 1j, 0; 0, 0, 1")
```

```
# output:
array('1, 1+1j, 0; 0, 1j, 0; 0, 0, 1', dtype='<U29')
```

I ask because `np.matrix` has a few deprecation warnings (in the help-documentation currently in my case), and this feature is very convenient when using python with numpy as a calculator. The mental load from having to remember to close and open the bracket after every row is taxing compared to a single semicolon.

Comment: See [related issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/13891).

Comment: This string parsing was included in `np.matrix` to make it more MATLAB friendly.

Comment: it is one of the very few good things about MATLAB in my opinion. It has not been added to arrays in any way then I take it? i.e. the answer is "not possible" or at least not without writing a custom function that I automatically load in all python sessions or something?

Comment: `numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.py` has all the code that makes `np.matrix` distinctive.  Right at the top is see a function that does your conversion,  `np.matrixlib.defmatrix._convert_from_string`.